# Enter key does not work on Netbeans 7.1

Tags: keyboard, netbeans

I installed Netbeans under Debian with PHP extension, but the enter key don't work on the code editor. Only on  PHP projects, it works fine in Java projects.

**UPDATE:**

I updated to Netbeans 7.1.2 and it works fine!

Comment: Hey danyel, since you solved your problem you can post your update as an answer, that's perfectly acceptable and it will be a lot easier to find the answer for people having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Also from http://forums.netbeans.org/topic46466.html

"... fixed the issue by klicking on the info icon left to the

It seems that the default is HTML 5 - and this generates a parser Exception. 
After switching the project default to the above mentioned setting I could use ENTER as normal - even on newly opened files."

Answer (score 1):

Please click on the Info (Bulb icon) on the top of the file or from where you start php code. After click on the bulb select "Change project default to HTML 4.01 Transitional" option and now you able to use Enter key normally.
Please check the Screen-shot attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I got the same problem with Netbeans 16 and 21. So...

As far as I have seen with Laravel projects, comments in blades (`{{-- ... --}}`) trigger strange behaviors, such as preventing new lines or even inserting tabs.

Strangely this doesn't always seem to happen, I think it is related to other Laravel code in the comment.

Removing them restores normal behavior.